# Usage of D in the Field

Tags: c++, c++11, d

I have tried to find some information on D. I do especially like this [comparison](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/cpp0x.html) with C++ to get an overview on what it is. 
Now I am asking myself: how often D is used in the field, and how much of a viable alternative is it to C++?

Comment: I think this is the kind of "question" that needs to be community wiki in order not to be closed outright.

Comment: Closely related questions include: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/743319/why-isnt-the-d-language-picking-up and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250511/does-the-d-programming-language-have-a-future

Comment: I think most C++ programmers are very happy with C++0x. Of course the syntax isn't ideal, *and so what*? C+ programmers are, more than anyone, used to that. The problem with D is that it is not a viable alternative. It is not yet stable enough or standardized enough, it is not widely enough supported, it is not compatible with the millions of lines of C++ code you may already have. And honestly, if compatibility with existing C++ code is not a requirement, there are far better languages than *anything* in the C family.

Comment: If you removed all bust the last paragraph, I think you stand a good chance of this question getting re opened

Comment: i want to express that i am a little surprised how the SO Community reacts to such a question. Okay, there we're related questions. Honestly, I searched SO before opening this question. That I couldnt find an answer sort of proves my Point. I explicetly didn't want this to become a flamewar, as i pointed out above. This is no C++ rant. Anyone who did actually read my post would have noticed. It's about whats holding people back to use it! And the point about GC was made to _prevent_ a flamewar. I wanted to have a realistic View on where D is and where it is going.

Comment: @Johannes:  It read to me like a rant, and had nothing to do with the question.  I agree with BCS - the last paragraph, while admittedly subjective, isn't argumentative.  I'd have voted to close this question if it hadn't already been closed, but I'd vote to reopen if you dropped everything but the last paragraph.

Comment: Well right now it's not even semantically a question, it's just a statement. It's nice that you tell us what you're asking yourself, but as it stands you aren't asking _us_ anything.

Furthermore, D _is_ competing with C++, so the "chance" it has of competing is 100%. I suspect you may want to reformulate that a little :)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, you were right. I just wanted to provide a context for my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think D is a great language, but what people might hold back from using it is that it is (afaik) not compatible with c++ libraries. So all libraries you can use have to be written in C or D. So if you are a C++ developer switching to D isn't so much fun.

Comment: D2 will have limited compatibility with C++ libraries.  http://digitalmars.com/d/2.0/cpp_interface.html
Also, if you have C wrappers around those libraries, D fully supports the C ABI.

Comment: why is that of particular concern? What are the libraries that are incompatible and why does'nt D provide its own?

Comment: Since D emphasizes that it should be simple to implement the language, so to keep the complexity down, it doesn't support everything in C++ (which is syntactically a very complex language) because that would mean practically having a C++ compiler in the D compiler. This reduces the number of libraries that can be interfaced with, and there's not a list of which ones work and which  ones don't. D doesn't provide it's own because it's still young - it only came out in 2007, whereas C++ has had decades to amass libraries.

Answer (score 4):

The primary impediment to wide spread use of D is the lack of a 1st class IDE (like VS), immature tools sets and libraries. The IDE issue is improving with [Descent](http://www.dsource.org/projects/descent) and it is expected/planed that once D version 2 comes out the the two libraries will merge. The tools issue is also improving but more slowly. (IIRC there has been some progress as of late on getting D support in the official GDB)

Comment: If you like Visual Studio, D may now be [an option for you](http://dsource.org/projects/visuald).

Answer (score 3):

I do not see it used much around me (scientific computing). D could be a viable alternative for many cases in scientific computing where C++ is used now. For me personally, two things are keeping me back from using it:

- No stable D2 specification yet. D2 and D2 Phobos is on par with (and arguably better) than C++ and the STL. D1 Phobos however is not even near a replacement. But since D2 is still a moving target, it may not be well-suited for programs yet.
- Lack of a D2 compiler that supports x86_64. This is absolutely problematic for my field, since datasets have grown so much that you need more than 4GB of memory to efficiently process data, and 64GB machines have become commonplace.

If these two problems are solved, I will seriously consider D in the future besides OCaml and Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

For me, D's biggest problem is the lack of a strong corporate backer or "crown jewel" software which uses it. Java had Sun. C had Bell Labs and had Unix written in it early. C++ had AT&T and afterward Microsoft. C# has Microsoft.

Comment: Not so. The hallmark of programmers is that they're lazy. Going to D is a lot of work without the C++ compatibility.

Comment: I don't agree either. What about Python? It had no "corporate backer" and is now in the top 10 languages (maybe even top 5 depending on what you're counting).